# Setting Node.js environment variables on `npm run` call

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

`package.json`

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_ENV=development node ./index.js"
  }
}
```

Is it possible, for example, to pass and override `NODE_ENV` on `npm run start`?

```sh
npm run start NODE_ENV=production
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add one more script

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_ENV=development node ./index.js",
    "production": "NODE_ENV=production node ./index.js"
  }
}
```

And then run

```
npm run production
```